# Meaning & usage of "buy me cake"

Tags: meaning, idioms

When someone says: "buy me cake", what's his meaning? Does it mean anything except its normal meaning?
Thanks

Edit: I've seen this in a language file of a computer program: "Buy Me Cake :)"
http://singularlabs.com/software/ccenhancer/

Comment: Well, you made me search if "buy me cake" is an idiom, because I have not encountered such idiom in my entire life. I know "piece of cake", though. If it's becoming a new idiom nowadays, I wonder what would it mean. Maybe "I'm hungry"?

Comment: I've seen quite a few questions with scant details, but this one takes the cake. (Near as I can tell, "Buy me cake" means "Purchase some cake for me," but some additional context might get me to reexamine the question.) As an aside, you might also be interested in [ell.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the free software CCleaner Enhancer wrote this in the [changelog](http://www.gratisprogramas.org/descargar/ccleaner-enhancer-1-4-2/):

> CCEnhancer has been updated for performance enhancements.
>
> Previously; the tool would make a connection to the definition file, ensuring that the server is responding. This caused the annoying “hang” before the download commenced, as it would take several seconds for the domain resolution and connection to take place. The definition file would be almost fully (if not completely) downloaded before the connection was dropped. The new version connects to a much smaller file to validate the connection, eliminating this hang.
>   The CCEnhancer icon has also been updated slightly, making it look better and reducing the size considerably.
>
> **Lastly, a “Buy Me Cake” button has been added which links directly to my paypal donate page.**

So, quite simply, because the software is free, if you like it you can click the button and donate some money to say thank you, which the author can use to buy cake (or something else). The suggestion is to donate not a lot, but just enough for some cake.

It's similar to other *donateware* where the suggestion is to tip the author for a coffee, you may see "Buy me a cup of coffee" for other software.

Here's the [French language file](http://assiste.free.fr/Assiste/ftp/CCEnhancer/lang.French.locale), which shows the corresponding texts used when it's used in French:

> Buy Me Cake :)|Offre-moi un kouign-amann :)

A [kouign-amann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kouign-amann) is a round, Breton cake.

Answer (score 2):

I assume: You're translating the user interface of this program and "language file of a computer program" refers to the file that contains the original strings as well as the translated strings for a certain language. I think you should also provide a screenshot if this is the case.

If my assumption is correct, I *guess* this is related to donations. When a program is distributed free of charge, it's usual that the programmer(s) use a phrase like "buy me a pint of beer", "buy me a cup of coffee" to encourage the users to donate to the development of the program. So, "buy me cake" would refer to something similar: "donate to the program so that I can enjoy a piece of cake on your tab".

Comment: +1 Yes! I've seen this type of appeal on freeware programs before. It's an ironic/tongue-in-cheek plea for funds.

Comment: Your assumptions are [correct!](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/132979/9001)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your explanations are great. I should try to ask more clear questions from now on.

Answer (score 1):

"Buy me cake" isn't an idiom.  Without the surrounding context, it's almost impossible to say what it means (other than "buy me a cake").

What did you mean by "language file of a program"?   If it's source code, it must be a comment - and programmers are notorious for putting in odd comments.